# Change field order in table using SQL query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am adding new field to existing table using ALTER TABLE statement. Is it possible to change filed index by query so that field is not on last place in designer mode?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it is, no.  Other than re-ordering the columns in any `SELECT` statements which use them, to actually re-order the physical table would require:

- Create a new table with the intended column order;
- Copy all of the data from the existing table to the new table;
- Drop the existing table;
- Rename the new table to the previous table's name.

Naturally, doing all of this in a single atomic action is very important so that data isn't missed between steps 2 and 3.  So cutting off application access during the window of time that this is done is a good idea.